# Unable to load trained model in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, metrics

I trained a CNN and saved it in my Google Drive, now I am trying to load it and test it with a different dataset, however I'm having problems to load it. Can someone help me, please?

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
newmodel =  tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/Programa2/New_UNet.h5')
newmodel.summary()
```

The error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    376       if obj is None:
    377         raise ValueError(
--> 378             'Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + object_name)
    379     # Classes passed by name are instantiated with no args, functions are
    380     # returned as-is.

ValueError: Unknown metric function: dice_coef
```

dice_coef is a function created in a code called Metrics to evaluate the segmentation result.

`model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy',Metrics.dice_coef,Metrics.precision,Metrics.sensitivity,Metrics.specificity])`